# Code suggestions & autocomplete of react native is not working in atom

Tags: atom-editor, react-native

I am coding in atom text editor for writing react native mobile application. I want code suggestions like when I am writing inbuilt classes of react native library. I have to write completely own, seems like I am writing code in notepad.

Atom is not hinting & autocomplete for in built methods/classes of react native while typing.

Do I need to install any plugin to get this working ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Atom** alone is not able to provide autocomplete for builtin react-native classes nor your own classes, but its plugin-architecture allows you bring this up nevertheless.

---

### *A little sidenote*

*Apparently the people behind atom.io changed their URL-structure. The following URLs might not work anymore. Instead of downvoting this answer everybody is invited to find out the right URLs and edit this answer with the new URLs. Don't be so destructive*

---

First you should install "**[nuclide](https://nuclide.io/)**" as it comes with special features for your react native development.
Moreover you need this:

[https://atom.io/packages/atom-react-native-autocomplete](https://atom.io/packages/atom-react-autocomplete)

There are further usefull plugins like:

- https://github.com/aakashns/atom-react-native-snippets
- https://atom.io/packages/react-native-components
- and so on

[image]

You should use the search within the "install packages" section in Atoms preferences pane.

[image]

*As a side note:*

However, after working one year with Atom i switched to Microsofts [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which is much more performant and really brilliant with autocompletion and typehinting once you configured it the right way and installed some plugins. Checkout Google for further information. There are some usefully blog posts around this topic:

1. https://medium.com/react-native-training/vscode-for-react-native-526ec4a368ce
2. http://equimper.github.io/2017/02/25/why-i-moved-away-from-atom-to-visual-studio-code-and-my-setup/

Be prepared: the first link offers at the end(!) a fast way to setup everything from scratch with only one step.

Comment: i've finally found the links regarding MS Visual Studio Code and added them at the end to my answer

Comment: https://atom.io/packages/atom-react-native-autocomplete this link is broken

Comment: http://equimper.github.io/2017/02/25/why-i-moved-away-from-atom-to-visual-studio-code-and-my-setup/
does not work either

Comment: Thanks for downvoting an older answer due to changed URLs Schemes. WTF...